# Non-blocking multi-sign of transaction

Tags: multi-sig

Here is my scenario:

I have a transaction that needs to be signed by A and B. I want to create this transaction and send it to each of them to be signed. The issue is that I need to to merge the two signature into the same transaction.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Something like the following steps would help you..

(I took this directly from the JS SDK documentation)

- Use TransactionBuilder to build a new transaction.
- Make sure to set a long enough timeout on that transaction to give your signers enough time to sign!
- Once you build the transaction, use transaction.toXDR() to get the base64-encoded XDR string.
- Send this XDR string to your other parties. They can use the instructions for getKeypairSignature to sign the transaction.
- They should send you back their publicKey and the signature string from getKeypairSignature, both of which you pass to this function (addSignature of Transaction object)

Please review the docs here:
[Stellar JS SDK TXN Documentation](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Transaction.html#addSignature)

Comment: I must have missed it, thank you a lot it seems exactly what I need indeed